# html table with data from database without populating database row id php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am constructing html table with data  queried from database using php. I also need to perform edit,delete operations on that table. I am saving the 
**database row id** as hidden input field in each table row.

What I am doing is when user clicks on the particular row I getting the row id using jquery and performing edit/delete operations on the database table 
using ajax,php

But the problem here is when user inspects element he can see the ids of each row. So if the user is technical expert he can edit the row id and change the
value of other rows in database table.

Generally how to handle this type of situations without populating database row id in table.

Comment: Please add some code you have tried.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information to give any sort of answer. Please come up with specific examples and code and people here will be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is that kind of expert to look in inspector and manipulate that hidden info, and that is something that has to be strictly not possible to change, you could send guid or some custom backend function that encrypt / decrypt the info from user table..

Answer (score 1):

Populating the row id is a correct, but if the user can change the values of some records but not others, the correct solution would be check server-side if the user has the privileges to edit the row that is currently trying to edit

Answer (score 1):

You can take more info from the any cell of the row.
You save the id in your hidden input then take with jquery any cell and if the data cell and the id are not same in DB don't do anything if have relation then Delete.
hope it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

For more security you have to create hash of each row and send to ajax page and verify both the hash . since it is a one way encryption so you hash for each row is unique..

Here is what i am saying to you

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_protect_sensitive_data_in_URL's